# How to get data from database and send it as sms?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, smsmanager

The application that I'm creating needs to send sms to the phone number. The body of the sms consists of data from the database.

```
public void MyMessage() {
       Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getAllData();

       DBHelper db = DBHelper.getInstance();
       String phoneNum = etphonenumber.getText().toString().trim();

       if (etphonenumber.getText().toString().equals("09xxxxxxxxx)) {

               SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
               String spamMessage = "Srno: " + cursor.getString(0) +
                                    "Date: " + cursor.getString(1) +
                                    "In: " + cursor.getString(2) +
                                    "Out: " + cursor.getString(3) +
                                    "Req by:" + cursor.getString(4) +
                                    "JO#: " + cursor.getString(5) +
                                    "Co: " + cursor.getString(6) +
                                    "BR: " + cursor.getString(6) +
                                    "CNum: " +cursor.getString(7);
               ArrayList<String> sms;
               sms = smsManager.divideMessage(spamMessage);
               smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNum, null,sms,null, null);
               //smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNum, null, spamMessage, null, null);

               Toast.makeText(this, "Message has been sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               Intent intent=new Intent(Login.this,ListActivity.class);
               startActivity(intent);
               finishAffinity();

       } else if (etphonenumber.getText().toString().equals("")) {
           etphonenumber.setError("Enter Your Phone Number First");
           etphonenumber.requestFocus();
       } else {
           etphonenumber.setError("Number is incorrect!");
           etphonenumber.requestFocus();
       }
   }
```

I tried to use the code above but my app keeps crashing. I expect the output will be that I will receive an sms that has the data from the database.

This is what appears in my logcat:

```
2019-10-30 10:46:42.033 6033-6064/com.example.android.tfe E/MemoryLeakMonitorManager: MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist!
2019-10-30 10:46:42.061 6033-6078/com.example.android.tfe E/AwareLog: AtomicFileUtils: readFileLines file not exist: android.util.AtomicFile@70a9e29
2019-10-30 10:46:52.005 6033-6033/com.example.android.tfe E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.tfe, PID: 6033
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6663)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6635)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:794)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26199)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6663) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6635) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:794) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26199) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987) 
     Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:468)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
        at com.example.android.tfe.Login.MyMessage(Login.java:85)
        at com.example.android.tfe.Login.send(Login.java:66)
```

Comment: Can you add your crash log?

Comment: @Zookey my logcat is empty :(

Comment: You need to add your crash logs so we can help. Have you enabled the added the permissions to the manifest? Have you requested the user to allow those permissions?

Comment: @apmartin1991 I've put what my logcat is showing. plus I edited the code. I get the same result. The app just crashes down.

Comment: We cannot write for your application? It doesn't work so. Answering this stacktrace, you have problem with DB handling. Problem in your code in the method `dbHelper.getAllData();`